# Deploy bitbucket public repo as application dependancy through composer on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, composer-php, bitbucket

My application's dependencies are managed using composer, and one of dependency is from bitbucket public repo. Which is working fine locally, but when I deploy it to Heroku its not resolved and even not getting any error.

My composer.json is:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/repo.git"
    }
],

"require": {
    "vendor/repo": "dev-master"
},
```

Thank for any help.

Comment: I think there might be a problem with ssh keys composer needs to access the bitbucket repository.

Comment: @HonzaHaering for public repo as well? I will give a try and see. Thanks

Comment: @HonzaHaering I tried the solution and working fine now even though I am getting some class auto-loading issue but composer is resolving dependencies as expect. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I am able to fix problem. Actually it was SSH Keys issue as mentioned by @HonzaHaering in comment. I thought it will be useful for someone to add solution here.

First check do you have any SSH-Key on Heroku by:

```
ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you don't have key then generate key using:

```
ssh-keygen -C test@example.com -t rsa
```

You will be prompted for passphrase enter passphrase if you want and at the end you will be presented with fingerprint etc. on successful key generation.

Than go to bitbucket account and follow instructions to add generated SSH Key to account:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Add+an+SSH+key+to+an+account

Comment: Good, it works. Also, I think if you reference public repo like `https://bitbucket.org/vendor/repo`, then no need for ssh keys. Sorry, it didn't come to my mind before :-)

Comment: Yes, that was in my mind, and even i tried but might be I was doing something wrong :) . Otherwise for public repo it should work this way as well.